# Hibernate one-to-many mapping with composite key on the many side

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many, composite-key

I'm facing the following problem with Hibernate mapping - spent pretty much time doing a research but haven't found an analogous case. Let me describe the simple database schema we're dealing with.

```
create table point(
POINT_ID integer primary key,
x integer,
y integer);

create table segment(
POINT_A_ID integer references point(POINT_ID),
POINT_B_ID integer references point(POINT_ID),
constraint segment_PK primary key(POINT_A_ID,POINT_B_ID)
);
```

As you can see, a Segment is just a line between two points, identified by the pair (POINT_A_ID, POINT_B_ID).
I only want to have this association mapped from the Point's side. I've figured out I should have two collections, e.g. 
private Set segmentsA, segmentsB;

Here are my xml mapping files:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="entities.model.Point" table="POINT">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
        <column name="POINT_ID" />
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="x" type="int">
        <column name="X" />
    </property>
    <property name="y" type="int">
        <column name="Y" />
    </property>
    <set name="segmentsA" table="SEGMENT" lazy="false" cascade="all-delete-orphan" >
        <key column="POINT_A_ID" not-null="true" update="false" />
        <one-to-many class="entities.model.Segment"/>
    </set>
    <set name="segmentsB" table="SEGMENT" lazy="false" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
        <key column="POINT_B_ID" not-null="true" update="false" />
        <one-to-many class="entities.model.Segment" />
    </set>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="entities.model.Segment" table="SEGMENT">
    <composite-id name="segmentPK" class="entities.model.SegmentPK">
        <key-property name="pointAId" >
            <column name="POINT_A_ID" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="pointBId"> 
            <column name="POINT_B_ID"/>
        </key-property>
    </composite-id>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I'm trying to persist some Points and Segments between them (having added one Segment instance to segmentsA and segmentsB sets of appropriate Point instances), I get the following error:
`org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: entities.model.Segment column: POINT_A_ID (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")`

I'll be very grateful for your advice on this case :)